# How to integrate Google reCaptcha in ios Obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I want to integrate Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise in my iOS Project, which is in Obj c.
I followed this link but can't install Pod file,
https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#direct-download
After adding script, when i run pod update, got this error
[image]
Need little guidance.